# MySQL Type for Storing a Year: Smallint or Varchar or Date?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, optimization

I will be storing a year in a MySQL table:  Is it better to store this as a smallint or varchar?  I figure that since it's not a full date, that the date format shouldn't be an answer but I'll include that as well.

Smallint? varchar(4)? date? something else?

Examples:

- 2008
- 1992
- 2053

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I would use the [YEAR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/year.html)(4) column type... but only if the years expected are within the range 1901 and 2155... otherwise, see Gambrinus's answer.

Comment: Well I feel silly for having completely missed this type.  Thanks

Comment: It's not a widely used type.  The only advantage it has over the smaller int types is that you can use date functions on it.

Comment: As it's only one byte wide, it only supports years in range '1901' to '2155'

Comment: @Paul: That's true... I've noted that in my answer now.

Comment: @Paul: I'd believe that MySQL would be updated before then to avoid a Y2.155K bug — I hope.  Good concern either way.

Comment: thanks for mentioning the year-datatype - didn't know that one

Comment: Yeah thanks for the tip - I'd never heard of this one either!

Answer (score 14):

I'd go for small-int - as far as I know - varchar would take more space as well as date. second option would be the date.

Comment: Not to mention small int will sort much faster.

Comment: For those using Laravel's (or Lumen's) Eloquent, this seems to be the only option.

Answer (score 7):

My own experience is with Oracle, which does not have a YEAR data type, but I have always tried to avoid using numeric data types for elements just because they are comprised only of digits. (So this includes phone numbers, social security numbers, zip codes as well, as additional examples).

My own rule of thumb is to consider what the data is used for. If you will perform mathematical operations on it then store it as a number. If you will perform string functions (eg. "Take the last four characters of the SSN" or "Display the phone number as (XXX) XXX-XXXX") then it's a string.

An additional clue is the requirement to store leading zeroes as part of the number.

Furthermore, and despite being commonly referred to as a phone "number", they frequently contain letters to indicate the presence of an extension number as a suffix. Similarly, a Standard Book Number potentially ended in an "X" as a "check digit", and an International Standard Serial Number can end with an "X" (despite the ISSN International Centre repeatedly referring to it as an 8-digit code http://www.issn.org/understanding-the-issn/what-is-an-issn/).

Formatting of phone numbers in an international context is tricky, or course, and conforming to E.164 requires that country calling codes are prefixed with a "+".

Comment: I don't agree with this, a phone number is called a number for a reason, it only contains numbers. How you present the number to the user, is irrelevant to how you save it in the database, which should only contain data, not format characters.

Comment: @Tim it is not only about representation. You'll habe to search against phone number field. how are you going to handle it with an integerfield?

Comment: @Tim When storing phone numbers as numbers, how do you store "073345678901" without losing the initial zero?

Comment: @DavidAldridge you don't, local phone numbers (without a country code) always start with a leading zero, so it's obsolete. You can format the number on the front/back-end as an international phone number (prepend the country code) or a local phone number (prepend a zero).

Comment: @Tim You mean "In North America ...". True in the UK, India, Iran, Japan, some numbers in Pakistan, South Korea, Taiwan, Australia, but not in all countries ... I mean I'm just reading from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_conventions_for_writing_telephone_numbers. How would you store "1-800-GOT-JUNK" in the US?

Comment: @DavidAldridge 18004685865 like the real number it is. It's true the trunk prefix differs per country, but mostly 0 is used. However this isn't applicable if you always format as an international number and let the user choose a country + country code.

Comment: @Tim Since nobody presents phone numbers as a simple list of digits, what's the first programatic step you'd always do when presenting a phone number to a user, or before prepending the required zeroes, or prefixing with the "+" sign in accordance with RFC 2806? And what's the SQL predicate for searching for UK phone numbers with an area code of "01204"? In both cases you need to convert to a string first. If it acts like a string then it is a string, and if it acts like a number then it is a number.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Still, all the things you mention is front-end related, if it's a number you can format it to every representation you like, if you going to save strings like 1-800-JUNK or 1 - 800 - JUNK or 1800-JUNK, you never have an unified data selection, if you search for '1800' you would never get the desired results. It's much easier to replace and strip all non-digits from a user input or even replace chars to numbers at the front-end (or back-end even) before it's saved to the database. Then you may present it to the user, in any format you'd like.

Comment: @Tim It wouldn't make sense to store spaces and dashes. You can strip those out and store the result as a string, which can preserve characters (if desirable), allow prefix-based searching, and formating based on i18n logic. I'm not saying that you *can't* store them as integers, but as soon as you want to do anything with them, you'll first convert them to a string. Always. You are never, ever going to apply numerical formating, or perform a mathematical operation on them, because they are just strings that usually comprise only digit characters.