# Which column type for storing the year field in a table with rows of yearly data

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, database-design

My Laravel web app uses the [schema builder](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#adding-columns) for database portability, so the [MySQL-specific YEAR column type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611105) is not available.

I want to be able to sort and select rows of data by year (including `BETWEEN`). What's the best portable column type for storing year values?

Comment: How about `int`?  Or, `char(4)` would also work.

Comment: Isn't it possible to use raw statements to in the schema builder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What's the best portable column type for storing year values?

`smallint` is a good choice to represent years, and it's ANSI SQL, so will work in most databases. It will last until the year 32767.

Some databases support `create domain` which basically lets you create your own types. You could create a `year` domain for other databases. I prefer the simplicity of smallint for year though.

Answer (score 1):

Could you do something like this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('mytable', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        // columns
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    DB::statement('ALTER mytable ADD year YEAR' );

}
```

Comment: This wouldn't be a portable solution.

Comment: To further my understanding can you tell me what you mean by portable? Do you mean so you can switch between databases so it's not mySql specific for example?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
Schema::table('tablea_name', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE table_name ADD year YEAR(4);');
});
```

Portable solution would be if Laravel provides any way to access this method (in `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php`) in upcoming versions:

```
/**
 * Add a new column to the blueprint.
 *
 * @param  string  $type
 * @param  string  $name
 * @param  array   $parameters
 * @return \Illuminate\Support\Fluent
 */
protected function addColumn($type, $name, array $parameters = array())
{
    $attributes = array_merge(compact('type', 'name'), $parameters);

    $this->columns[] = $column = new Fluent($attributes);

    return $column;
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't be a portable solution.

Answer (score 0):

As at Laravel 5.8, you can do this:

```
$table->year('birth_year');
```