# MySQL Numeric Type

Tags: mysql, database, date, numeric

Hi I need to add a column to my table where I should insert a value that indicates the year relative to the row. So it will just be a number, always integer, always bigger than 0, always 4 digits... so what's the best numeric type for the column and how would the phh query to add the column would be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Type for Storing a Year: Smallint or Varchar or Date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611105/mysql-type-for-storing-a-year-smallint-or-varchar-or-date)

Comment: Yes thanks, still I'd like to have the final php string to call the query to add the column as smallint... and btw what does the number inside the smallint () mean? "smallint(1)" what's the difference between this and smallint()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the SMALLINT the minimum value is -32768 and the maximum value 32767 an interger can be used for bigger numbers between: -2147483648 and 2147483647

for example:
SMALINT(3)

means a number from -32768 until 32767 the (3) represents the display width of the field

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you mean with display width of the field? Can you give me some examples and also the final php query to add the column smallint?

Comment: The display width does not constrain the range of values that can be stored in the column. Nor does it prevent values wider than the column display width from being displayed correctly. For example, a column specified as SMALLINT(3) has the usual SMALLINT range of -32768 to 32767, and values outside the range permitted by three digits are displayed in full using more than three digits. And I should make a "Dummy" table. put the data from your old data into the dummy after that you can delete your original table

Comment: Than you can make a completely new table and use the right column datatypes. if the new table is made(With your old table name) you can insert the "Dummy" table data into the new one.

Comment: Can you explain the display width range with some examples? I don't understand why I would need it or how it can be useful. By the way I only need values of 4 digits so what would be the best choice, smallint() or smallint(0) or smallint(1) ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest datatype YEAR()

*Note: Values allowed in four-digit format: 1901 to 2155.*

Otherwise SMALLINT() should be fine.

Statement would be:

`ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name datatype`